# Saving multiple times on single click

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

i have a search text box ,search result will show a graph ,i am saving that result in DB

But first time it will save properly ,second time it will save 2 times ,third time 3 times ,

```
$('#twitsave1').click(function(el)
{ 

    if ( $("#twitsave1").prop('checked') == true ){

    //console.log( el.timeStamp);
    var reId=$(this).next().next().html();
    console.log(reId);
    var key=$('.searchBar input[type="text"]').val();
    var timeStamps = el.timeStamp;
    var loginname = AppAPI.getUser();
    var logTypes = 'EVIDENCE';
    var dataSources = 'Twitter';

    AppAPI.showLoadingBar('Saving'); 

    var data=JSON.stringify({
        "login":loginname ,
        "value": reId,
        "logType": logTypes,
        "title": 'Twitter - '+key,
        "dataSource":dataSources,
        "timeStamp": timeStamps,
        "searchDateRange":startdate+":"+endDate
   });

   console.log(data);
   var url=getApplicationRoot() +'/api/dao/logEntry';
   $.ajax({
    type:"POST" ,
    url:url,
etc.......
```

In console.log(data) i am getting 3 or 4 times same data 
Please help

Comment: try http://api.jquery.com/one/ .The issue might be with `click` getting fired multiple times

Comment: The root cause is that you are binding the click event multiple times. I advice you to correct that instead of doing a work around with `.one()`

Comment: @techfoobar : What's wrong with using `one` ?

Comment: @harsha the problem is not the whether to use `one` or not, but an error in the logic of the script. `click` should work just fine if it was bound correctly. Instead, the clickhandler (somehow - that's not visible in the provided code) is bound again each time it is called. So with each consecutive click you have bound one more handler to the element. Of course you can work around that perfectly with `one`, however it is better to just detect the error in the script (since binding and unbinding handlers is also a performance issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be with click getting fired multiple times. Use [**`.one()`**](http://api.jquery.com/one) instead. This handler will only execute once.

Answer (score 2):

Probably this click binding: `$('#twitsave1').click()` is executed again within the click handler.

- Do you call a refresh/redraw function where this click() binding occurs again?
- Does the click trigger a AJAX call which returns javascript code that is added to the page? than check if that javascript doesn't add a the click() binding again.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add disable or readonly attribute to the button. That user will not able to click it again and again.

Comment: That's not really a solution